# How can I query a database with a value to get another value with sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to query a database with a unique id value and get the value of a column within the same row.

```
class Accounts(Base):
     __tablename__ = 'Accounts'

    id = Column(Integer, unique=True)
    site = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    accounts = Column(Integer)
    followers = Column(Integer)
```

How can I query the table with an id number and return the value of the site cell?

Answer (score 5):

If you just want the value of that specific column--i.e. "SELECT column_name FROM ..." instead of "SELECT * FROM ..."--you can specify it in the query.

```
accounts, = session.query(Account.accounts).filter_by(id=account_id).first()
```

You can even specify multiple:

```
accounts, followers = session.query(Account.accounts, Account.followers).filter_by(id=account_id).first()
```

Answer (score 4):

This is covered in the [Query docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter_by). A query returns one or more model instances representing rows, and column data is stored on these instances as attributes.

```
account = session.query(Accounts).filter_by(id = <some_id>).first()
print account.site
```